# Rebuild other projects that are not referenced when F5 is pressed

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with two projects:

- `MainApp`
- `PlugIn`

The `PlugIn` **is not referenced** by the `MainApp` but loaded dynamically after the `MainApp` started.

I now have the issue that when I change something in the `PlugIn` and press `F5`, the `MainApp` starts but loads an old version of the `PlugIn` and I have to explicitly click on it with the right mouse button and rebuild it.

Do you know some trick how I can *force* `Visual Studio` to rebuild all projects in a solution regardless whether they are referenced somewhere or not when I press `F5`?

Comment: Choose Rebuild All. You can mess with the toolbar settings and keyboard shortcuts to assign 'Rebuild All' to something easy for you to use

Comment: The referenced question contains an exact solution for your problem.

Comment: @dymanoid coool! It worked - thanks ;-) I'll leave this question here in case someone else is looking for it using different wording, what do you think?